# Skipping input for which no grammar is written

Tags: antlr, antlr3, abstract-syntax-tree, antlr4

I have written grammar to parse the 'interface' blocks (a block is bounded by `!\n`) in the following snippet.

```
!
interface FastEthernet 1/0
    no ip address
    shutdown
!
ip route 0.0.0.0
!
router bgp 10
    <skipped...>
!
router ospf 1
    <skipped...>
!
interface Vlan 100
    ip address 192.168.20.1
    no shutdown
!
```

---

I have not written grammar for the 'ip route' or 'router bgp' or 'router ospf' blocks, but it is (and similar blocks are) prone to appear in the input. How do I go about skipping the 'unwanted' and proceed with only the 'intended' blocks? Am new to ANTLR, but have learnt to write grammar for similar stuff in the past couple of weeks. I have started with ANTLRv3.5 and v4 is going to be new.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like you would with multiline comments. When you encounter a block start that you are not interested in skip any following token until you see a new block start. Do the next check and so on. In order to have this loop in the parser instead of the lexer you still need to have lexer tokens for any of the input tokens, otherwise the lexer will complain. Multiline comments are usually written as lexer rule however, so if you want to do it similarly there's the problem that you would have to define "interesting" blocks at lexer level which is really not the right place for this.